# JavaScript syntax madness: pointer to eval function is not the eval function?

Tags: javascript, syntax

The following needs to be in function scope, since the strange behavior does not occur is interactive console mode.

Following function returns 5 as expected

```
(function() { var x = 5; return eval("x"); })()
```

A simple transparent(ish) change:

```
(function() { var x = 5; var j = eval; return j("x"); })()
```

yields an error:

```
ReferenceError: x is not defined
```

Is this some kind of strange security measure?

Comment: Just a site note - `"use strict"` does not allow to set `var j = eval;`: http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second example is an *indirect* call to `eval`. Indirect calls to `eval` are evaluated in the global scope, where `x` is not visible:

```
var x = 10;

// This will return 10
(function() { 
    var x = 5; 
    var j = eval; 
    return j("x");
})();

// This will return 5
(function() { 
    var x = 5; 
    return eval("x");
})();
```

From [the spec](http://es5.github.com/#x10.4.2):

> 1. ...if the eval code is not being evaluated by a direct call to the eval function then
>
> a. Initialize the execution context as if it was a global execution context...

Comment: Is this specific to eval? I checked with a simple function and it seemed the copied reference retained the context.

Comment: @PeterAronZentai - Yes, this is specific to `eval`. Have a read through the section of the spec I've linked to.

Comment: Appendum question: why is window.eval treated as an indirect call since global.something should be equivalent with something, aint?

Comment: @PeterAronZentai - I'm not entirely sure without following it all through in detail in the spec, but it means that the result of evaluating `window.eval` does not fit the conditions required in [this part of the spec](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.2.1.1).